# Cannot publish chatbot in Azure. After click "Direct line Channel" button, error is occurred

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I make a chat bot on Azure, check on webchat test.
Webchat test is successful, as shown in the image below.
[webchat test is success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDgtn.png)

For publishing this chat bot to Direct Line.
I click "constitute Direct Line channel" button in Channel category.(shown as below image)
[click "Direct Line Channel" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHcZU.png)

Clicked this button, transited ti error page.
This error page says "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.".(shown as below image)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DCvd.png)

This error also occur at other publishing button (teams,cortana,Slack...)
I cannot resolve this error.
Please tell me how to resolve this error.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a service issue, are you able to create a support ticket in Azure?

Comment: Thank you resonce.
Today I try to click "Direct Line Channel" button, it work fine.
I think it is temporary azure link error.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I click "Direct Line Channel" button, it work fine.
I think this matter is occuered by temporaly link error.